# How do wafers translate to computer hardware?

Tags: integrated-circuit

I am trying to figure out the relation between wafers produced in a fab and computer hardware.

Comment: That is a process that would take more than a few books to explain.

Comment: I am trying to figure out what you are actually asking... In a fab a die is produced and packaged, the components are then soldered on boards that are part of computer hardware. Either ask something more specific or expect this question to be closed.

Comment: The thing is that I don't know enough to be more specific.. I know that fabs produce wafers. I know the final result is computer hardware, What is the missing link? At least getting pointed in the right direction would be helpful

Answer (score 4):

Semiconductor chips are not fabricated individually.  It is more efficient to create a whole bunch at a time from one large slab of silicon, then break it apart into individual chips later.  That slab is called a *wafer*.

After a chip is separated from the wafer, it is put into a package so that the chip itself is enscased and protected from the elements.  Only those nodes intended to be connected to externally are wired out of the package via its pins.  This whole assembly is then often referred to as a "chip", since it is a single unit from this point forwards.

Multiple chips and other electronic components are then soldered to a circuit board, wired to some external parts like the power supply and front panel buttons, encased in a chassis, etc, to make a whole computer.

Answer (score 2):

This is *very* high-level, but it's someplace to start!

A wafer is a disc of silicon.  It is "etched", using various means, so that it's structure contains the transistors that make up the desired circuit.

There are many copies of the same circuit in one wafer.  These copies are then separated from each other.

Each small silicon circuit then gets packaged into an IC, complete with pins, legs, pads, BGA connections, etc.

I hope very simplified overview helps lead you in the right direction :)